# Python traceback module for beginners

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and am finding it difficult to understand the official document for the traceback module 
http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/traceback.html

If someone could please guide me on how to extract the traceback paramenters ( offending line of code etc) , I would be very greatful.

I could also use some understanding on how traceback functions if there are two exceptions in the code , can we pass traceback for them both

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/traceback.html#traceback-examples). The last line of code prints the line number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take a look at these tutorials that helped me out:

[Some general info about exception handling.](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/09/12/python-101-exception-handling/)

[Python Exception Handling Techniques](https://doughellmann.com/blog/2009/06/19/python-exception-handling-techniques/)